# passing a function in the if statement condition filed

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

My question is about best practice, I have a long if else statement, I am wondering if I can extract the conditions to a separate function and then pass them as the condition. Please see below =>

```
if (functionA (a, b)) {
    // do something
} else if (functionB (a, b)) {
    // do something else 
}

function functionA (a, b) {
    return a - b === 0
}

function functionB (a, b) {
    return a * b != 1
}
```

Comment: Your example is totally correct. Did you even try it? Or I'm not getting what is your problem.

Comment: @Oen44 oh yes, it does work, I am not saying it does not work. I am asking if this is right practice? Is this a correct way of extracting?

Comment: It's completely correct.

Comment: is this a normal practice? I can not find code written in this way, hence my question

Comment: Did you check every code in the universe? Using functions to check if somethings is true or false is used in almost every project. `isUserLogged`, `canAccessPage` etc.

Comment: of course I did not hehe, thank you

Comment: Posted answer with better explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have some data about user.

```
var userId = 1;
var userGroup = 'admin';
```

Now lets write some conditions

```
if(userId === 1) {
    // UserID is 1
}
if(userGroup === 'admin') {
    // UserGroup is admin
}
```

It works and all but we can make that a little bit more clear.

```
function isUserId(_id) {
    return userId === _id;
}
function isUserInGroup(_group) {
    return userGroup === _group;
}

if(isUserId(1)) {
    // User id is 1
}
if(isUserInGroup('admin')) {
    // User is in group admin
}
```

Looks better and is easier to read.